# Thunderbolt port stopped working

Tags: usb, thunderbolt

turning on my ASUS Vivobook laptop with Kubuntu 23.04 this morning I realized that my docking station doesn't work properly. I thought the problem was with the dock itself, but it turned out it's something to do with the Thunderbolt port. I tried with two different chargers to plug in only the charger and nothing happened. In the beginning I was thinking that the port was fried, and I started investigating.

Running `lspci -v` gave me this output:

```
0000:00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 146, IOMMU group 7
        Memory at 6131270000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
        Kernel modules: xhci_pci

0000:00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0 (rev 01) (prog-if 40 [USB4 Host Interface])
        Subsystem: Device 2222:1111
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, IOMMU group 7
        Memory at 6131200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
        Memory at 6131295000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: thunderbolt
        Kernel modules: thunderbolt
```

Then I install `boltctl` to try to find some more details, but the `boltctl list` doens't return anything. The single output that I've got is from `boltctl domains`

```
 ● domain0 f0976972-e5ee-8780-ffff-ffffffffffff
   ├─ bootacl:  0/0
   └─ security: iommu
```

I still think that the port is not fried based on the fact that is still visible as USB device, and I still hope it's caused by something else.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fixed it. It turned out to be the most simple and nonlocigcal solution. I just turned off the latop, holded up the power button for like 30 seconds to flush and...everything is back to normal.
No idea what caused this issue, during the night the electricity was stopped for few minutes, but the laptop was connected just to the power cable, not the Thunderbolt port.

Anyway, problem solved.